# Navigator.storage.estimate() returns much more space available than what i really have in my hard drive. Why?

Tags: browser, blazor, storage, webassembly

I have a cross-platform app built in Maui. I want to show the user how much space he has available in the device he is using.

For Android, Catalyst and iOs, i am using DriveInfo, which works as expected. But in the browser, I think the only way to access storage is through the cache provider.

Navigator.Storage.Estimate() returns almost 300 GB of free space. 60% of my hard drive capacity, but that 60% should be the maximum it returns in case the drive was empty. Which is not. I only have 150 GB available.

Has someone any idea why it is behaving this way?